# Running mongodb forever using forever in windows

Tags: node.js, mongodb, forever

I am trying to run MongoDB server forever locally on Windows 10. And for that I'm using forever server.js which throws an error i.e, Forever is not installed.

I did npm install. But then too showing the same error. 
I have followed [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-mongodb-on-ubuntu-14-04) guide, but it's for Ubuntu. I am using Windows 10.

I need something like if I close the server cmd also, it should keep running.

Answer (score 0):

In Windows, you can use the mongod command to register Mongo as a service

mongod --directoryperdb --dbpath "C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.4\data\db" --logpath "C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.4\log\mongo.log" --logappend --rest --install

1. Open the cmd(command prompt) as administrator
2. run the above command
3. open services and search for mongo service
4. If it is not running already, click start to start the service

Answer (score 0):

You need to install mongo as a service.
To do so,

1. Open cmd in administrator mode.
2. Create two directories to store data and logs

> mkdir c:\data\db
>
> mkdir c:\data\log

3. Create a configuration file. The file must set systemLog.path. Include additional configuration options as appropriate.For example, create a file at C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.6\mongod.cfg that specifies both systemLog.path and storage.dbPath like this:

> systemLog:
>
> destination: file
>
> path: c:\data\log\mongod.log
>
> storage:
>
> dbPath: c:\data\db

4. install mongo service, run the following command:

   > mongod.exe --config "C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.4\mongod.cfg" --install
5. Start service using: `>net start mongodb`

   6. To stop service use : `>net stop mongodb`

You can refer official documents [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-windows/)

Answer (score 0):

```
1. mongod --install --dbpath D:\data\db --logpath D:\log\mlog.txt
2. net start MongoDB
```

> All above command should be run as administrator and you can change dbPatha and logpath with your path

[How to start & stop a mongo DB server from the command line](https://singhak.in/how-to-start-stop-a-mongo-db-server-from-the-command-line)