# Not able to start MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I have installed MongoDB in the C drive. the bin folder is in the below path.
i have also created the data and log folders.within the data folder have created a folder named db

```
C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.4\bin
```

i have opened the cmd and navigated to the bin folder and type the below command

```
mongod --directoryperdb --dbpath C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.4\data\db --logpath C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.4\log\mongo.log --logappend --rest --install
```

i am getting the below error

[image]

and when i type the below command also i am getting an error

[image]

guys i am clueless ,pls help me out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

can you try this:

```
mongod --directoryperdb --dbpath "C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.4\data\db" --logpath "C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.4\log\mongo.log" --logappend --rest --install
```

The error can be because of the `space` between "Program Files".

For the second error, it is because MongoDB is not installed as a service.
You can check you [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47656551/7579549) answer to see how to setup mongo as a service.

Comment: Happy to help! :)